# WWW::Scripter package using 1.2GB of memory while being used for webscraping

Tags: perl, web-scraping, web, www-mechanize

I am not super familiar with this package in the first place. I discovered that the use_plugin('JavaScript') method consumes alot of memory through a profiler. I swapped this method for the plugin('JavaScript'), though the memory consumption was lower, i could not event go through the login page form of the websites i am supposed to scrap.

Globally defined:

```
my $scripter = WWW::Scripter->new();
$scripter->use_plugin('JavaScript')
```

```
if(my $form = $scripter->form_with_fields("Password")){
  $form->value('Password', $conf->{'moxa_p'});
  $form->submit();
}else{
  print "dbg +> form 1.0 not found";
}
```

Tried using the delete and undef keyword but it does not help at all!

Comment: When RAM issue is in the question, the strict minimum is to share details on your **computer**, **OS** and **versions of softwares**. Moreover, if the executed Javascript is buggy, this is normal. But without knowing anything about _the context_ nor having the Javascript code, it's pretty difficult to help here.

Comment: Btw, If you need to handle JS I'd rather suggest Selenium

Comment: If you know Javascript, https://pptr.dev use less system ressources than Selenium (bloatware) @zdim

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @GillesQuénot  "_...pptr.dev..._"  -- thanks for recommendation --- but I thought there was no driver for Perl for it (puppeteer)?  They want this from Perl

Comment: Maybe give a try to https://metacpan.org/pod/Playwright if you insist to use Perl. Never tried, but it should takes less ressources than Selenium.

Comment: @GillesQuénot "_As a programmer, switching language should not be an issue ... if you insist to use Perl_"  -- um, _they_ are asking a question with Perl?   I don't have anything to do with any of it :)

Comment: @GillesQuénot (As for me, I don't have a problem with languages. Can't really count all that I've used...  But, again, that is irrelevant here)

Comment: What is the most irrelevant is the lack of context from OP zdim ;) Another lib to try: https://metacpan.org/pod/Firefox::Marionette

Comment: I have to use Perl because of company restrictions. I am running this program from a Windows 10 virtual machine with 8GB RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reduce stack of cached pages (WWW::Scripter WWW::Mechanize)

Use max_docs in WWW::Scripter or stack_depth in WWW::Mechanize.  WWW::Machanize man page recommends setting in to 5 or 10.

**man WWW::Scripter**

> **max_docs**
> The maximum number of document objects to keep in history (along with their corresponding request and response objects). If this is omitted, Mech's stack_depth + 1 will be used. This is off by one because stack_depth is the number of pages you can go back to, so it is one less than the number of recorded pages. max_docs considers 0 to be equivalent to infinity.

**man WWW::Mechanize**

> •   **"stack_depth => $value"**
> Sets  the  depth  of  the page stack that keeps track of all the downloaded pages. Default is effectively infinite stack size.  If the stack is eating up your memory, then set this to a smaller number, say 5 or 10.  Setting this to zero means Mech will keep no history.